# Using ForkManager and Perl properly?

Tags: perl

My developer recently disappeared and I need to make a small change to my website.

Here's the code I'll be referring to:

```
my $process = scalar(@rows);
$process = 500 if $process > 500;
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($process);
```

This is code from a Perl script that scrapes data from an API system through a cron job.  Every time the cron job is run, it's opening a ton of processes for that file.  For example, `cron-job.pl` will be running 100+ times.

The number of instances it opens is based on the amount of data that needs to be checked so it's different every time, but never seems to exceed 500.  Is the code above what would be causing this to happen?

I'm not familiar with using ForkManager, but from the research I've done it looks like it runs the same file multiple times, that way it'll be extracting multiple streams of data from the API system all at the same time.

The problem is that the number of instances being run is significantly slowing down the server.  To lower the amount of instances, is it really as simple as changing `500` to a lower number or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code simplifies to

```
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(500);
```

It means: Limit the the number of children to 500 at any given time.

- If you have fewer than 500 jobs, only that many workers will be created.
- If you have more than 500 jobs, the manager will start 500 jobs, wait for one to finish, then start the next job.

If you want fewer children executing any given time, lower that number.

```
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new(50);
```

Answer (score 1):

To lower the number of instances created, yes, just lower 500 (in both cases) to something else.

[Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) is a way of using fork (spawning new processes) to handle parallel processing.  The parameter passed to new() specifies the maximum number of concurrent processes to create.

Comment: It's the max _concurrent_ processes. It'll still do 10,000 if you tell it to, but in the example above - only 500 at a time will be running.